# Question on installing PEAR on a shared server

Tags: php, pear

I need to install PEAR on a shared server & was reading this page: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Down the bottom part it says:

*Go to go-pear  and save as go-pear.php. Copy go-pear.php to your server and open the corresponding URL in your browser, for example http://example.com/pear/go-pear.php.*

But then it says:

*Do not forget to protect the pear directory if you did not do already before the installation: Make it unreadable and not executable from external (i.e. put it outside public_html).*

Which directory are they talking about exactly? One you enter during the installation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the directory which contains the pear files (where pear was installed)
It's always a good idea and best practise to keep library folders secured and out of reach for users (The best way is to move them out of the html root (The folder which you can access from your webbrowser) but not all webhosts allow you to access these parts of the server). 
Otherwise people could access sensible files in your librarys (get information about your setup/ weaknesses etc.).

For example:

you could have a library which contains a readme.txt changelog.txt etc. if somebody finds this file on your server he knows which version you use therefore knows if your website/ server might be attackable if in this particular version of the library are any known security holes (many people forget to update their librarys).

Answer (score 1):

On our shared hosting I installed PEAR in the home directory with no problems.

This is a FreeBSD machine, I fetched the main pear FreeBSD package and one or two additional PEAR-* packages I needed, and extracted them in my home directory (`~/pear/`, NOT the WWWROOT).
How to extract the package depends on your OS, but you can usually just use `tar` ...

After that I added `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/MYUSERNAME/pear/');` to a base class that's always executed and presto! PEAR works great.

Answer (score 0):

On shared hosting, there is a good chance that you won't be able to install pear by ourself.

The best way to deal with that is to ask you hosting company if there is a way to have PEAR on your hosting.